# Am I using onehot-encoded features correctly in the Machine-Learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, one-hot-encoding

I have 14 features and 1 label for my `RenadomForestRegressor` model by using Sklearn-packages in `Python`.  I have 10000 data under each column, so the size of the arrays `Feature: (10000, 14)` and `Label: (10000, 1)`

13 out of 14 features are in string format so I used the `OneHotEncoder` from `sklearn.preprocessing` for these 13 string features as below (1 Feature is in float format). Below I only show one feature example:

```
values = array(df['receiver_bic']) # This is one of the features, BIC-code for banks like "HANDSESS", in string format with limited values

# integer encode
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)

# binary encode
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories='auto')
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
receiver_bic_onehot = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)

The shape of the final array RECEIVER_BIC_ONEHOT: (10.000, 622)
```

After doing the same process for each string feature (13 features), I got the onehot-encoded feature sizes as:

```
# Shapes of 13 OneHot_encoded features
(10000, 622) ,(10000, 397), (10000, 325), (10000, 331), (10000, 319), (10000, 235), (10000, 24), (10000, 4), (10000, 196), (10000, 78), (10000, 118), (10000, 128), (10000, 55)
```

Finally I collected these features under X as:

```
X=np.c_[OneHot_Feature_1, OneHot_Feature_2, ... , OneHot_Feature_13, Numeric_Feature_14]

y = df[target_col] # Target column

X = np.array(X) # Converting Feature and Target to numpy arrays
y = np.array(y)

# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
```

Finally I get the array shapes as

```
Training Features Shape: (7000, 2833)
Training Labels Shape: (7000, 1)
Testing Features Shape: (3000, 2833)
Testing Labels Shape: (3000, 1)
```

Before using in the model, I transform the `Features: X` with `StandardScaler()`

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train=scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Finally I insert these arrays into the `RandomForestRegressor` model

```
est_RFR = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10) 
est_RFR = est_RFR.fit(X_train,y_train.ravel()) # ravel() is needed to convert the (n,1) shape into (n,)
```

My questions:

- Was my process above for using `OneHotEncoder` for multiple features correct?
- Even if it was correct, the X.shape before OneHotEncoder was `(10000, 14)` and after OneHotEncoder was `(10000, 2833)`. My gut feeling says that I have unnecessarily big amount of `Feature-columns` in the model, using 2833 columns instead of 14. Is there a more proper way of using this?
- I am trying to convert the OneHot-encoded values back to their original values with `inverted = label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(receiver_bic_onehot[:, :])])`. But output of `print(inverted)` gives only one original value instead of the whole column. How should I write this code?

Comment: Can you be more specific than to say those features were in "string format"? For example, there's a big difference between a feature that's one of 7 distinct string labels - in which case, a 7-dimensional one-hot encoding makes sense – versus a string that might be a free-form text or a list of overlapping tags, in which case other encodings would make more sense.

Comment: @gojomo each feature has limited amount of values, they are not fed with free text, they are fed with predefined values. For example, the feature for bank BIC-codes has 622 distinct values. Another feature has 397 distinct values, and another one has 325 distinct values.

Comment: OK, then your transformed data seems to be the right shape, and I wouldn't worry about "unnecessarily big amount of feature columns" - that's what's needed to categorically-encode the data. (If size-of-representation becomes an issue, and your downstream steps can handle it, you might then try to ensure sparse representations are used/preserved.) Unsure the issue with your attempted reversing code, but I suspect there should be a use of `onehot_encoder`, & its `inverse_transform()`, rather than `argmax` in there. (Can you confirm conversion of the one-hots into an array of label-indexes, 1st?)

Comment: @gojomo when you asked about "conversion" If you mean that my model worked, then yes. I got my result in 6 seconds and the R^2 score was 0.78 with RandomForestRegressor. I got around 0.66 R^2 score with MLPRegressor.

Comment: @gojomo  I am very new in this area so I have 2 questions which I couldn't find a good answer yet: 1) I have one feature in float format with size (10000, 1) and there is no problem to split it in the model. For the feature with string format with 622 distinct values, why does the model need 622 columns? Can't I convert the string content (10000, 1) into a float content (1000,1) and split it in the model like I did with the other original float feature?

Comment: I changed the code above from `inverted = label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(receiver_bic_onehot[:, :])])` to `inverted = onehot_encoder.inverse_transform([(receiver_bic_onehot[:, :])])` and I got `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.` Can you guess the problem here?

Comment: If the 622 alternate values map naturally to some scalar value, sure, you could convert each one to a single number. But in all likelihood, they do not: value 'A' in that field is not reasonably thought of as any fraction or multiple of value 'B', but something else entirely. By encoding it as a totally separate, yes/no (1.0/0.0) field, you let the downstream algorithms decide each's import independently. OTOH, shoehorning them into any single numerical field enforces an assumption on them, and how they might relate to any answer.

Comment: So if they're truly mutually-exclusive alternatives, like different org-names, or action-types, etc, you shouldn't mind that your feature-modeling gives every single one a categorical on/off field - it's natural & effective, and easily handled by the memory/algorithms, so your sense of it seeming "too much" is what should change.

Comment: Without full reproduction code & an error-stack, no guesses as to what's wrong with your inverter code. It sounds like it should be a separate, focused question with a minimal. complete synthetic example to demonstrate the encoding steps, then the exact failed-decoding-attempt & error-stack/message.

Comment: yes, i will start another topic. the error was that my array was 3D. I tried to fix it by reshaping it to 2D with `nsamples, nx, ny = receiver_bic_onehot.shape
d2_receiver_bic_onehot = receiver_bic_onehot.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))`, I got another error as `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)` :)